# Исключение повторяющихся записей

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Как сделать чтобы адрес не повторялся?

```sql
    select * from room JOIN reserve ON room.id_room=reserve.id_room 
    where  (datearrive < '2020-08-10' or dateleave >'2020-08-11')
```

```
+---------+---------------+-------+--------+------------+---------+------+--------+------------+------------+
| id_room |     adres     | price | images | id_reserve | id_room | name | phone  | dataarrive | dateleave  |
+---------+---------------+-------+--------+------------+---------+------+--------+------------+------------+
|       1 | Черепанова 22 |  1000 |        |          1 |       1 | sad  | fdsdf  | 2020-08-15 | 2020-08-16 |
|       3 | Ленина 28     |  1000 |        |          2 |       3 | dasd | dsadsa | 2020-08-16 | 2020-08-17 |
|       4 | Ленина 35     |  1000 |        |          3 |       4 | fdsd | fsdf   | 2020-08-16 | 2020-08-17 |
|       1 | Черепанова 22 |  1000 |        |          4 |       1 | вфы  | вфыв   | 2020-08-17 | 2020-08-18 |
+---------+---------------+-------+--------+------------+---------+------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: @Egorithm спасибо.

Comment: Не так быстро. Во-первых, вам нужно указать, какие столбцы определяют уникальность. DISTINCT работает со всеми столбцами.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DISTINCT тут не нужен. У вас все записи уникалшные и ничего не повторяется.

Для id_room=1 есть две брони id_reserve=1,4. У вас скорее условие неверное, вот и выводятся две брони и для них одинаковый адрес два раза.